# Localhost, Eclipse, java applets, and php code; applet not running

Tags: java, php, eclipse, applet

Running Apache/PHP on this PC.

I am using Eclipse >> Export Java > JAR file or Runnable JAR file

I copied and pasted some code to test running Java on a web server, here is the class.

```
package com.dane;

import java.awt.*;

import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawingLines extends JApplet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JApplet applet = new DrawingLines();
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(applet);
        f.setSize(400, 400);
        f.setLocation(200, 200);
        applet.init();
        // If you override start method
        // applet.start();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    int width, height;

    public void init() {
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            g.drawLine(width, height, i * width / 10, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried exporting it both as a simple Jar and a Runnable Jar, with all sorts of combinations of settings.

The only thing I haven't tried is creating my own manifest, or rather, one that works.

Here is my php file. There are no php tags, and the result was the same even when I had php code in there:

```
<APPLET CODE="DrawingLines.class" WIDTH="250" HEIGHT="22" codebase="/Test/test.jar"> </APPLET>
```

I have also tried:

```
<APPLET CODE="DrawingLines.class" WIDTH="250" HEIGHT="22"> </APPLET>
```

The general result is this:

```
load: class DrawingLines.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DrawingLines.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I **can** run the applet within eclipse.

If it can't find the class in an external environment, I am assuming I am screwing up something during the creation of the jar. I've checked the eclipse Run Configurations for the project.

Under Java Applet, it shows a run configuration named after my class, DrawingLines.
[image]

If I try to export a runnable jar, here are the launch configurations it shows, not sure if it is important but the class one isn't there.
[image]

Any idea what is going on here?

regards,

dane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `archive` attribute instead of the `codebase` attribute, if you want to indicate a jar file.